Getting error "error starting screen record" while recording screen through Android emulator
I want to record a screen within Android Studio emulator itself. But when I turn on start screen recording through the notification window getting above error
Note- I dont want to use Android Studio record and Playback
Device - pixel 6 Pro Android Version 12
https://app.screencast.com/6tFtmbcKChceY
